# cookie in ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have this setting:

- html page at https://foo.bar.example.com
- with a cookie for the domain .example.com
- with a javascript doing an ajax get to retrieve a json from https://baz.example.com

specifically, I'm using jquery and doing a `$.ajax("https://baz.example.com/.../resource.json")`

I expected the ajax call to send the cookie to the server, but nothing is sent. If I add the option `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the jquery method I succesfully see the cookie sent, but I was expecting that this was not necessary.

Why is `foo.bar.example.com` a different domain from `baz.example.com`?
Why isn't the cookie shared? if I do a "manual" get opening the JSON url with the browser from a different tab I see the cookie is sent.

Comment: Cookies only cross domains if the subdomain was explicitly whitelisted when the cookie was created.

Comment: but the cookie was created for `.example.com`; shouldn't it means it is for all the subdomains?